# how to check whether a stream has uppercase , lowercase and digits or not using stream in java

Tags: java, java-stream

```
/*package whatever //do not write package name here */

import java.util.*;

import java.lang.*;

import java.io.*;

class GFG {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //code
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while(t--!=0)
        {
            String S = sc.nextLine();
             char []arr=S.toCharArray();
             Arrays.stream(arr).filter(arr.hasLowerCase()).filter(arr.isUpperCase()).filter(arr.isNumeric()).filter(forEach(arr->System.out.println("Yes")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you actually want to ask on how to check if a String contains uppercase and lowercase letters as well as digits? If so, then this might help: [How to check whether a string contains lowercase letter, uppercase letter, special character and digit?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8794940)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the methods defined in `Character` class to filter the input character stream.

```
input.chars()
            .filter(X -> Character.isUpperCase(X) ||
                         Character.isLowerCase(X) ||
                         Character.isDigit(X)
                   )
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

EDIT:

To get a boolean result of whether such character exists in the stream, use `anyMatch()` instead of `filter`.

```
    if (input.chars()
            .anyMatch(X -> Character.isUpperCase(X) || Character.isLowerCase(X) || Character.isDigit(X))) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
```

EDIT 2:

Im not sure if you are checking if the stream contains ALL OF THEM or AT LEAST ONE OF THEM. The above answer is for contains at least one. If you are looking for all of the characters, just change the `||` to `&&`.

Comment: actually i need to print whether it contains uppercase lowercase and numeric in yes or no

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: This will say if it contains _any_ of those things. The question asks for _all_ (… and …).